# App widget layout: text line above an image, center inside bounding box

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I've got a very simple app widget layout: a line of text above an image.

The image should scale to fit the widget's bounding box (maintaining aspect ratio) and the text should be left-aligned with the image below it. Together they should appear in the middle of the widget's bounding box.

I can't get that to work. The best I managed was aligning to top-left of the bounding box, as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

I can't specify a `scaleType` which would align top-center and I also can't make the image view take just as much space as it needs for the image.

Comment: You should use Relative layout or Frame Layout, or Coordinate layout, they will work better for adjusting the view which linear layout does not.

Comment: can you show image what actually you want but what actually you have?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, [Here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKRlB.png), If you want your layout should visible as you want in landscape mode, you have to make another layout for the landscape mode or keep your view in portrait mode.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/img"
    android:text="Text Line"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/signuptop" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This seems to work for the tall bounding box, but fails in a wide one because there's no constraint on the image view to leave space for the text view. I guess specialized layouts for each situation may do it.